# How to get the right date from string using Date Formatter

Tags: ios, nsdate

I want to get NSDate from a string. The input strings are in format of : "2014-06-27 15:21:02"

I use the code below but i get nil:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:edditedString];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you look into the [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) you can see that your format string should be:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

To be able to resolve the date from your string..

Just to simplify your code, the initializer on dateFromString is not necessary, it is easier doing:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:edditedString];
```

Sample of this in swift:

[image: Swift Playground]

Comment: well it worked but its returning a wrong time! i get"2014-07-06 09:15:34 +0000" from "2014-07-06 13:45:34"!!!!!

Comment: @devdev101 Timezones.

Comment: Can you run through each step and ensure that your DateFormatter is correctly set up? Cause like you can see in my edited post it is working in exactly this way with your string. also check that your debugger already stepped over the line or log the variable out so you ensure you definitely have the variable setted